# How to access context and setstate outside build method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

How to access context and setstate outside build method in Flutter?

To make the app responsive I need context.

I get error "Undefined name 'context'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."
When I write context here:-

```
class Portfolio extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext context1;
  const Portfolio({
    required this.context1,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Portfolio> createState() => _PortfolioState();
}

DragAndDropList buildList(CardsList list) => DragAndDropList(
      header: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 15.0,
          top: 10,
          bottom: 10,
          right: 15,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              list.header,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF100F32),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: responsiveWidth(14, context),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Icon(
              Icons.more_horiz,
              color: Color(0xFF364766),
              size: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      children: list.cards
          .map(
            (item) => DragAndDropItem(
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 280,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(item.text),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      footer: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, bottom: 10),
        child: addCard == false
            ? OPopupTrigger(
                triggerWidget: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Color(0xFF80899D),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Add a card',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF80899D),
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                barrierDismissible: true,
                popupHeader: SizedBox(),
                popupContent: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('Hehehe'),
                      Spacer(),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 280,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 25),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (newText) {
                        list.textField = newText;
                      },
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        hintText: 'Enter a title for this card...',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF838EA0),
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF838EA0),
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF838EA0),
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          list.cards.add(
                            Cards(text: list.textField, position: 1),
                          );

                          print(list.textField);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF026AA7),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          ),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 80,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Add card',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          addCard = false;
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Color(0xFF80899D),
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );

class _PortfolioState extends State<Portfolio> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    lists = widgets.map(buildList).toList();
  }

  late List<DragAndDropList> lists;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
```

Full code file:-

```
import 'package:expandable_reorderable_list/expandable_reorderable_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:o_popup/o_popup.dart';
import 'package:project_submission/responsive.dart';
import 'drag_and_drop_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class CardsList {
  final String header;
  final List<Cards> cards;
  String textField;

  CardsList({
    required this.header,
    required this.cards,
    this.textField = '',
  });
}

class Cards {
  final String text;
  final int position;

  const Cards({
    required this.text,
    required this.position,
  });
}

List<CardsList> widgets = [
  CardsList(
    header: 'To-do',
    textField: '',
    cards: [
      Cards(
          text:
              'Trello Tip: Card labels! What do they mean? (Click for more info)',
          position: 1),
      Cards(text: 'Project "Teamwork Dream Work" Launch Timeline', position: 2),
      Cards(text: 'Stakeholders', position: 3),
    ],
  ),
  CardsList(
    header: 'header2',
    textField: '',
    cards: [
      Cards(
          text:
              'Trello Tip: Card labels! What do they mean? (Click for more info)',
          position: 1),
      Cards(text: 'Project "Teamwork Dream Work" Launch Timeline', position: 2),
      Cards(text: 'Stakeholders', position: 3),
    ],
  ),
  CardsList(
    header: 'header3',
    textField: '',
    cards: [
      Cards(
          text:
              'Trello Tip: Card labels! What do they mean? (Click for more info)',
          position: 1),
      Cards(text: 'Project "Teamwork Dream Work" Launch Timeline', position: 2),
      Cards(text: 'Stakeholders', position: 3),
    ],
  ),
  CardsList(
    header: 'header4',
    textField: '',
    cards: [
      Cards(text: 'Hello1', position: 1),
      Cards(text: 'Hello2', position: 2),
      Cards(text: 'Hello3', position: 3),
    ],
  ),
];

bool addCard = false;

bool greyArea = false;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // This is the theme of your application.
          //
          // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
          // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
          // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
          // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
          // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
          // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
          // is not restarted.
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Wait());
  }
}

class Wait extends StatefulWidget {
  const Wait({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Wait> createState() => _WaitState();
}

class _WaitState extends State<Wait> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Portfolio(
                      context1: context,
                    )));
      },
      child: Text('Wait'),
    );
  }
}

class Portfolio extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext context1;
  const Portfolio({
    required this.context1,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Portfolio> createState() => _PortfolioState();
}

DragAndDropList buildList(CardsList list) => DragAndDropList(
      header: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 15.0,
          top: 10,
          bottom: 10,
          right: 15,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              list.header,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF100F32),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: responsiveWidth(14, context),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Icon(
              Icons.more_horiz,
              color: Color(0xFF364766),
              size: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      children: list.cards
          .map(
            (item) => DragAndDropItem(
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 280,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(item.text),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      footer: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, bottom: 10),
        child: addCard == false
            ? OPopupTrigger(
                triggerWidget: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Color(0xFF80899D),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Add a card',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF80899D),
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                barrierDismissible: true,
                popupHeader: SizedBox(),
                popupContent: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('Hehehe'),
                      Spacer(),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 280,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 25),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (newText) {
                        list.textField = newText;
                      },
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        hintText: 'Enter a title for this card...',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF838EA0),
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF838EA0),
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF838EA0),
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          list.cards.add(
                            Cards(text: list.textField, position: 1),
                          );

                          print(list.textField);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF026AA7),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          ),
                          height: 30,
                          width: 80,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Add card',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          addCard = false;
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Color(0xFF80899D),
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );

class _PortfolioState extends State<Portfolio> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    lists = widgets.map(buildList).toList();
  }

  late List<DragAndDropList> lists;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xFF2B1B81),
                    Color(0xFFDD499D),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Text(
              'Project Management',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
                top: 30,
              ),
              child: DragAndDropLists(
                listWidth: 300,
                axis: Axis.horizontal,
                listPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                itemDragOnLongPress: false,
                children: lists,
                onItemReorder: onItemReorder,
                onListReorder: onListReorder,
              ),
            ),

            // Row(
            //   children: [
            //     DragTarget(
            //       onAccept: (data) {
            //         setState(() {
            //           widgets.add(data);
            //           widgets.remove(data);
            //         });
            //       },
            //       onWillAccept: (data) {
            //         setState(() {
            //           greyArea = true;
            //         });
            //         return true;
            //       },
            //       onLeave: (data) {
            //         setState(() {
            //           greyArea = false;
            //           widgets
            //               .sort((a, b) => a['position'].compareTo(b['price']));
            //         });
            //       },
            //       builder: (context, _, __) => SizedBox(
            //         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            //         child: Column(
            //           children: [
            //             Padding(
            //               padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, top: 30),
            //               child: Container(
            //                 width: 300,
            //                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //                   color: Color(0xFFEBECF0),
            //                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            //                 ),
            //                 child: Column(
            //                   children: [
            //                     Text(
            //                       'Project Resources',
            //                       style: TextStyle(
            //                           color: Color(0xFF5D6C83),
            //                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            //                           fontSize: 12),
            //                     ),
            //                     for (var wid in widgets)
            //                       Column(
            //                         children: [
            //                           Padding(
            //                             padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            //                             child: Draggable(
            //                               child: Container(
            //                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //                                   color: Colors.green,
            //                                 ),
            //                                 child: Text(wid['text']),
            //                                 height: 100,
            //                                 width: 100,
            //                               ),
            //                               data: wid,
            //                               feedback: Container(
            //                                 color: Colors.red,
            //                                 height: 100,
            //                                 width: 100,
            //                               ),
            //                               childWhenDragging: SizedBox(),
            //                             ),
            //                           ),
            //                           DragTarget(
            //                             onAccept: (data) {
            //                               setState(() {
            //                                 widgets.add({
            //                                   'text': data['text'],
            //                                   'position': 1
            //                                 });
            //                                 widgets.remove({
            //                                   'text': data['text'],
            //                                   'position': data['position']
            //                                 });
            //                               });
            //                             },
            //                             onWillAccept: (data) {
            //                               setState(() {
            //                                 greyArea = true;
            //                               });
            //                               return true;
            //                             },
            //                             onLeave: (data) {
            //                               setState(() {
            //                                 greyArea = false;
            //                               });
            //                             },
            //                             builder: (context, _, __) {
            //                               print(_);
            //                               return SizedBox();
            //                             },
            //                           ),
            //                         ],
            //                       ),
            //                     greyArea == true
            //                         ? Container(
            //                             color: Colors.grey,
            //                             height: 20,
            //                             width: 100,
            //                           )
            //                         : SizedBox(),
            //                     SizedBox(
            //                       height: 8,
            //                     ),
            //                   ],
            //                 ),
            //               ),
            //             ),
            //           ],
            //         ),
            //       ),
            //     ),
            //   ],
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onItemReorder(
    int oldItemIndex,
    int oldListIndex,
    int newItemIndex,
    int newListIndex,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      final oldListItems = lists[oldListIndex].children;
      final newListItems = lists[newListIndex].children;

      final movedItem = oldListItems.removeAt(oldItemIndex);

      newListItems.insert(newItemIndex, movedItem);
    });
    print(lists);
  }

  void onListReorder(
    int oldListIndex,
    int newListIndex,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      final movedList = lists.removeAt(oldListIndex);
      lists.insert(newListIndex, movedList);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you got error?

Comment: Why do you need to pass context on widget constructor

Comment: That's a good question: you don't have to pass the context in the constructor, it is already included in the build method and it's accessible from everywhere inside a class that extends StatefulWidget (or Stateless, for that matter)

Comment: Yaa. I removed it from the constructer but I want to call context outside the class because if I take the function inside the class then the drag and drop function is not working.

Comment: Try creating variable inside state class instead of `StatefulWidget` and those who depend on context create helper method instead of variable